# Invalid recipient from docusign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to embed a docusign signature page into a website. but I get this error

```
Message=Error calling CreateRecipientView: {
  "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of 
  the specified envelope."
}
```

I'm using the .Net nuget client and here's the code I'm using (note I've changed guids and emails)

### Authenticate

```
string userId = "0570b3da-652e-4040-842e-65a0e6fc8133"; // use your userId (guid), not email address
string integratorKey = "cf73e7bb-e05d-4ce9-9cea-ac065dc894ac";
string host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(host);

string username = "my@email.com";
string password = "[password]";

// initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

// configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```

### Find account id

this was part of the [example code](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client#usage)

```
// we will retrieve this from the login API call
string accountId = null;

AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

//find the default account for this user
foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
{
    if (loginAcct.IsDefault == "true")
    {
        accountId = loginAcct.AccountId;

        string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };

        // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
        apiClient = new ApiClient(loginAcct.BaseUrl.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
        break;
    }
}
```

### Create Envelope from a template

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
tRole.Email = "recipient@email.com";
tRole.RoleName = "Leaseholder";
tRole.ClientUserId = tRole.Email;

List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole> { tRole };

envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;
envDef.TemplateId = "2504e3f0-f4d9-4eca-9fd3-3b26cfd6c086";

RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
{
    ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:64202/home/winning",
    ClientUserId = tRole.Email,  // must match clientUserId of the embedded recipient
    AuthenticationMethod = "email",
    UserName = tRole.Email,
    Email = tRole.Email
};

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var summary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
var receipients = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(accountId, summary.EnvelopeId);
ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, summary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);

return Content($"<h2>hmm</h2><iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"{viewUrl.Url}\"/>");
```

### Recipients on the template

[image]

### Recipients

```
{
"agents": [],
"carbonCopies": [],
"certifiedDeliveries": [],
"editors": [],
"inPersonSigners": [],
"intermediaries": [],
"recipientCount": "1",
"seals": [],
"signers": [
  {
    "clientUserId": "recipient@email.com",
    "creationReason": "sender",
    "deliveryMethod": "email",
    "email": "recipient@email.com",
    "isBulkRecipient": "false",
    "name": "",
    "note": "",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "recipientIdGuid": "52abdeea-2bd6-4108-97b9-170ca27d573a",
    "requireIdLookup": "false",
    "roleName": "Leaseholder",
    "routingOrder": "1",
    "status": "created",
    "userId": "0570b3da-652e-4040-842e-65a0e6fc8133"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT` error usually means that one of the following three property values specified for the Recipient within the Envelope doesn't exactly match the corresponding value that's been specified in the **Get Recipient View** request:

- `Name`
- `Email`
- `ClientUserId`

In your case (based upon the code you posted), I suspect that the `UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT` error is being caused by the fact that the info you've specified for the recipient ***does not*** include a value for the `Name` property -- where as the info you've specified when creating the `RecipientViewRequest` object ***does*** include a value for the `UserName` property (as it must).

To fix this error, I'd suggest that you try adding this line to the portion of your code when you're specifying information for the `TemplateRole` object (where "RECIPIENT_NAME" is the first and last name of the recipient).

```
tRole.Name = "RECIPIENT_NAME;
```

And then specify the same value for the `UserName` property of the `RecipientViewRequest` object:

```
UserName = "RECIPIENT_NAME",
```

(The value you specify as RECIPIENT_NAME will be the name that the recipient signs in the doc(s), so you should specify first name / last name of the person, not an email address.)

---

**UPDATE**

Re the subsequent `RECIPIENT_NOT_IN_SEQUENCE` error that you've mentioned in your comment, this error occurs when you call **Get Recipient View** for a recipient either before the Envelope has been sent or before it's "their turn" in the routing order to receive the Envelope. In your case, I suspect this is occurring because you're not setting the `status` of the Envelope to `sent` -- the recipient can't receive/access the Envelope until it's been sent. To resolve this error, set the status of of the Envelope when you're composing the `EnvelopeDefinition` object:

```
envDef.Status = "sent";
```

Comment: Thanks Kim, now I get a different error of 

    {
      "errorCode": "RECIPIENT_NOT_IN_SEQUENCE",  "message": 
      "The token for an out of sequence recipient cannot be generated."
    }

Comment: Happy to help, Scott. I've updated my answer to add info about this new error.

Comment: BTW -- I've updated the original portion of my answer to suggest that you set Recipient.Name to the person's first name / last name (not to an email address).

Comment: Thx Kim, that status update has got it working. I've also changed the UserName and tRole.Name as you've meantioned and it now prompts for a signature method